# How to touch a file and read the modification date in PHP on Linux?

Tags: php

I need to touch a file from within one PHP script and read the last time this file was touched from within another script, but no matter how I touch the file and read out the modification date, the modification date doesn't change, below is a test file.

How can I touch the log file and thus change the modification date, and then read this modification date?

```
class TestKeepAlive {

    protected $log_file_name;

    public function process() {
        $this->log_file_name = 'test_keepalive_log.txt';
        $this->_writeProcessIdToLogFile();

        for ($index = 0; $index < 10; $index++) {
            echo 'test' . PHP_EOL;
            sleep(1);
            touch($this->log_file_name);
            $this->_touchLogFile();
            $dateTimeLastTouched = $this->_getDateTimeLogFileLastTouched();
            echo $dateTimeLastTouched . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    protected function _touchLogFile() {
        //touch($this->log_file_name);
        exec("touch {$this->log_file_name}");
    }

    protected function _getDateTimeLogFileLastTouched() {
        return filemtime($this->log_file_name);
    }

    protected function _writeProcessIdToLogFile() {
        file_put_contents($this->log_file_name, getmypid());
    }

}

$testKeepAlive = new TestKeepAlive();
$testKeepAlive->process();
```

Comment: As an aside, whenever `touch()` is successful, the last modified time would usually be `time()` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the function `clearstatcache` found in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php)

> PHP caches the information those functions(filemtime) return in order
>   to provide 
>       faster performance. However, in certain cases, you may want to clear the cached
>       information. For instance, if the same file is being checked multiple times within a
>       single script, and that file is in danger of being removed or changed during that 
>       script's operation, you may elect to clear the status cache. In these cases, you can 
>       use the clearstatcache() function to clear the information that PHP caches about a file.

Function:

```
protected function _getDateTimeLogFileLastTouched() {
    clearstatcache();
    return filemtime($this->log_file_name);
}
```